# Does each component need its own resistor voltage divider circuit?

Tags: voltage-divider

I'm working with a couple of current transducers using the Emonlib library and an Arduino to read current through ADC inputs.

To introduce a DC bias their documentation uses a resistor voltage divider setup. My question is: since I am using 2 CTs can I piggy-back the second with its burden resistor into the voltage divider or does it need its own set of resistors and cap? Would this schematic work?

[image]

Comment: I don't see any particular issues with that but I'm still wary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can share the V divider since the CTs don't actually apply a load on it.

You might choose to also route the common point to another ADC input to measure it. That may eliminate errors in the 5V level or 10 kΩ resistors.